# How do I put a video from a source in Magento?

Tags: html, magento, video

I have this site:

[link](http://www.moment-of-style.com/special-projects?___store=en&___from_store=ru)

I want to insert a page on this video from my source.

I tried to use this code, but unfortunately not working

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="http://www.moment-of-style.com/media/wysiwyg/movie.avi" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://www.moment-of-style.com/media/wysiwyg/movie.avi" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Do you know why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your magento version?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Comment: you add video through cms page?

Answer (score 0):

Magento CMS pages support well the video tag. The format of your video is `AVI` in both places. It doesn't make a difference that you say the type is `mp4`, your video is still avi and can't be played.

After you convert your videos you can go in any page and after you click show editor paste the following html:

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="/your/path/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="/your/path/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```